# Pause button should stop images from switching

Tags: android, image, button

I'm trying to display a series of images upon entering an activity.
The displayed image should change after about 1 second, a button press should
pause the image from switching and a toggle of the button should enable switching again.

I've used a CountDownTimer to switch images via the onTick() rountine; however I'm not sure how to create the pause button feature.  Maybe using CountDownTimer isn't the best approach?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause button should stop images from switching…Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508773/pause-button-should-stop-images-from-switchingandroid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pause CountDownTimer but you can cancel it with .cancel() method. Then when toggle just create another CountDownTimer object and start from the last image.

Another way is to use a postDelayed runnable which can recursively call itself until paused:

```
public void myTimer(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {         
     @Override         
     public void run() {             
       //here call the next slide
       if(!pause) myTimer();             
      }     
     }, 5000); 
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to use the postDelayed runnable as you're suggesting...where exactly in the activity should I place this?  inside the onCreate?  or as an independent task inside the activity?

 is the recursive call like this...  this.postDelayed();

Comment: I have edited the code, so this method as you can see calls upon itself (recursive) every 5 seconds. If you set pause varibale to TRUE then it will stop. You place it below onCreate method but still within the activity class. You define pause varibale as boolean just bellow activity class statement and then call this method myTimer(); in onCreate. All you need is to enter the code or a call to another method to do your slides inside the run() here.

Comment: Super!  Working great now.  I use pButton.setOnClickListener(...) inside onCreate() to modify the pause varible.  By default pause is set to false.  After the button is toggled twice, the pause var returns to the false state and myTimer() has to be recalled in order to get the slides to switch again.  Cheers :)

Comment: There yu are, you are getting there :)